# Woocommerce function set_total_sales() is not setting and saving total_sales to database

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am working on a child theme in woocommerce.
In a function I am trying to use the default `get_total_sales()` and `set_total_sales()` to add total sales and save when it is called from AJAX(when a button is clicked to download).

```
function download_count_callback(){

    //get product id from AJAX POST
    $productid = $_POST['productid'];

    //get product by id
    $product = wc_get_product( $productid );

    //get the total sales number
    $downloadcount = $product->get_total_sales();
    error_log ("NUMBER was : ".$downloadcount );

    //add 1 to total sales
    $downloadcount += 1;
    error_log ("NUMBER should become : ".$downloadcount );

    //get the renewed total sales number
    $product->set_total_sales($downloadcount);
    error_log ("NUMBER NOW : ".$product->get_total_sales());

    wp_die();
}
```

Here's how the server log looks like:

```
[23-Feb-2020 12:44:44 UTC] NUMBER was : 0
[23-Feb-2020 12:44:44 UTC] NUMBER should become : 1
[23-Feb-2020 12:44:44 UTC] NUMBER NOW : 1
```

It looks fine, but no...
The downloadcount was not saved into the database.
When i refresh the page,

`get_total_sales()` will return back to 0.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this make a difference?

```php
function download_count_callback(){

    //get product id from AJAX POST
    $productid = $_POST['productid'];

    //get product by id
    $product = wc_get_product( $productid );

    //get the total sales number
    $downloadcount = $product->get_total_sales();
    error_log ("NUMBER was : ".$downloadcount );

    //add 1 to total sales
    $downloadcount += 1;
    error_log ("NUMBER should become : ".$downloadcount );

    //get the renewed total sales number
    $product->set_total_sales($downloadcount);

    $product->save();
    error_log ("NUMBER NOW : ".$product->get_total_sales());

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: silly me i didnt know it is required to run ` $product->save();` thanks that's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be helpful for someone if wants to set total sales for specific products.

**Note:** It will set total sales every time a page reloads. Please add some conditions etc. accordingly if you want it on specific scenarios.

```
// define the woocommerce_init callback 
function pc_set_total_sales( ) { 
    $query = new WC_Product_Query( array(
        'limit' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        // 'return' => 'ids',
    ) );
    $products = $query->get_products();

    foreach($products as $product){
        $myArr = [1674, 1213, 982];
        if ( in_array($product->id, $myArr) ){
            $product->set_total_sales(1);
        } else{
            $product->set_total_sales(0);
        }
        $product->save();
    }
};
add_action( 'init', 'pc_set_total_sales', 10 );
```